# How to resolve "Cannot find the setter for attribute" when using databinding in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I am trying to get databinding to work in Android Studio with custom BindingAdapters.

I have defined the following BindingAdapter in order to set an image:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:iconImage")
@JvmStatic fun setIconImage(view: ImageView, cool: Boolean){
        view.setImageDrawable(determineImage(cool, view.context))

}
```

However this raises the following error when building the project:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 
'app:iconImage' with parameter type androidx.databinding.ObservableBoolean 
on android.widget.ImageView.
```

This is my xml for the imageview:

```
    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/favorite"
            app:iconImage="@{myModel.cool}"
            app:imageRotation="@{myModel.stars}"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingBar"/>
```

I already tried changing the parameter type of the 'cool' parameter to ObservableBoolean but to no avail.

Comment: Is `setIconImage` top level function? Or is it placed in some class?

Answer (score 0):

The `cool` parameter that you're passing from your ViewModel is of Type `androidx.databinding.ObservableBoolean` it should be `Boolean` or `LiveData<Boolean>`

Comment: Thank you, I thought so as well at first. It turned out my issue was caused because of undefined gradle dependencies when using databinding with Kotlin. After adding the dependencies as described in this article my issue got resolved: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-frameworks.html#data-binding.